# Adicionar um array dentro de outro ja criado JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, array-multidimensional

Eu consigo criar uma array dentro de outro da seguinte maneira:

```
var meuArray = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]];
```

Com isso eu consigo verificar fácil as posições apenas chamando meuArray[x][y], onde x é qual o array que eu quero e y qual posição, por exemplo o numero dois corresponde a meuArray[0][1], ou o numero 6 corresponde a meuArray[1][2].
Até ai tudo bem, agora como eu faço para adicionar mais um array dentro do meu array? por exemplo tenho o seguinte array:

```
var meuSegundoArray = ["7","8","9"];
```

E quero adiciona-lo em meuArray, para que fique assim:

```
meuArray=[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]];
```

Ja tentei fazer:

```
meuArray += meuSegundoArray
```

nao deu certo, tanto quanto push.
Alguém tem alguma solução para este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É bem simples, utilize o push pra fazer isso:

```js
var meuArray = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]];
var meuSegundoArray = ["7","8","9"];

meuArray.push(meuSegundoArray);
```

Comment: Show!! eu tinha testado com push uma outra vez e não deu certo, nao sei o motivo, mas testei aqui e funcionou certinho, obrigado Douglas!!

Answer (score 0):

// Tenta usar o concat

var array1 = ['1','2','3']
var array2 = ['4','5','6']
var array3 = ['7','8','9']

var arrayTudo = array1.concat(array2, array3)

console.log(arrayTudo)